# Multiple users delete from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have "Office 365 Enterprise E3" subscription in Azure.

Suppose, I have a many users and i want to delete multiple users(more than 100).
so, how to do this ?

[image: Azure User list image with single delete option]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Delete user operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#DeleteUser) using Azure AD Graph API . If you want to reduce roundtrips to the server , try [batch operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing) on user entities. [Here](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-active-directory-batchprocessing) is a code sample shows how to query Azure Active Directory Graph API using Batch processing .

Another choice is using powershell .You can remove bulk users accounts(use csv file to store user accounts) by :

```
Import-CSV C:\Users.csv | Remove-MsOlUser –Force
```

[Here](http://www.ms4u.info/2015/03/bulk-remove-azure-active-directory-user.html) is an article shows bulk remove Azure Active Directory user using powershell .